# R: using foreach to read csv data and apply functions over the data and export back to csv

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-foreach

I have 3 csv files, namely `file1.csv`, `file2.csv` and `file3.csv`.

Now **for each** of the file, I would like to import the csv and perform some functions over them and then export a transformed csv. So , 3 csv in and 3 transformed csv out. And there are just 3 independent tasks. So I thought I can try to use `foreach` `%dopar%`. Please not that I am using a **Window** machine.

However, I cannot get this to work.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
numCores <- detectCores()
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(numCores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

filenames <- c("file1.csv","file2.csv","file3.csv")
foreach(i = 1:3, .packages = c("xts","zoo")) %dopar%{
  df_xts          <- data_processing_IMPORT(filenames[i])
  ddates                <- unique(date(df_xts))
}
```

IF I comment out the last line `ddates                <- unique(date(df_xts))`, the code runs fine with no error.

However, if I include the last line of code, I received the following error below, which I have no idea to get around. I tried to add `.export = c("df_xts")`.

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "unused argument (df_xts)"
```

It still doesn't work. I want to understand what's wrong with my logic and how should I get around this ? I am just trying to apply simple functions over the data only, I still haven't transformed the data and export them separately to csv. Yet I am already stuck.

The funny thing is I have written the simple code below, which works fine. Within the `foreach`, `a` is just like the `df_xts` above, being stored in a variable and passed into `Fun2` to process. And the code below works fine. But above doesn't. I don't understand why.

```
numCores <- detectCores()
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(numCores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)


# Define the function
Fun1=function(x){
  a=2*x
  b=3*x
  c=a+b
  return(c)
}

Fun2=function(x){
  a=2*x
  b=3*x
  c=a+b
  return(c)
}

foreach(i = 1:10)%dopar%{
  x <- rnorm(5)
  a <- Fun1(x)
  tst <- Fun2(a)
  return(tst)
  }
### Output: No error

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

**Update:** I have found out that the issue is with the `date` function there to extract the number of dates within the csv file but I am not sure how to get around this.

Comment: what does the function `data_processing_IMPORT` do? I can't find it in your given packages

Comment: All it does is read.csv  and convert it to xts object. That's all.

Comment: you are using `date()` wrong, you want to use `as.Date()`. `date()` returns your current system time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `foreach()` is correct. You are using `date()` in `ddates <- unique(date(df_xts))` but this [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/date) returns the current system time as POSIX and does not require any arguments. Therefore the argument error is regarding the `date()` function.

So i guess you want to use `as.Date()` instead or something similar.

```
ddates <- unique(as.Date(df_xts))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue about reading, modifying and writing several CSV files. I tried to find a `tidyverse` solution for this, and while it doesn't really deal with the `date` problem above, here it is -- how to read, modify and write, several csv files using `map` from `purrr`.

```
library(tidyverse)


# There are some sample csv file in the "sample" dir.
# First get the paths of those.

datapath <- fs::dir_ls("./sample", regexp = ("csv"))

datapath

# Then read in the data, such as it is a list of data frames
# It seems simpler to write them back to disk as separate files.
# Another way to read them would be:
# newsampledata <- vroom::vroom(datapath, ";", id = "path")
# but this will return a DF and separating it to different files
# may be more complicated.

sampledata <- map(datapath, ~ read_delim(.x, ";"))

# Do some transformation of the data.
# Here I just alter the column names.

transformeddata <- sampledata %>% 
  map(rename_all, tolower)

# Then prepare to write new files
names(transformeddata) <- paste0("new-", basename(names(transformeddata)))

# Write the csv files and check if they are there
map2(transformeddata, names(transformeddata), ~ write.csv(.x, file = .y))
dir(pattern = "new-")
```